# Undesirable results while interpolating

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I'm trying to create a surface plot from (x,y,z) data on an irregular grid. The datasets are located along diagonal lines of positive gradient in the (x,y) plane. The method is illustrated below

```
xi = linspace (min(x), max(x), 1000);
yi = linspace (min(y), max(y), 1000);
zi = linspace (min(z), max(z), 400);
[XI YI]=meshgrid(xi,yi);
F = TriScatteredInterp (x,y,z);
Vi = F(XI,YI);
surf(Xi,Yi,Vi);
shading interp;
view(2)
```

An example result is shown below:

[image]

The data should be smooth in the x direction (so at y=860 there should be a single, continuous blue dip). I think the problem is that the interpolation is being carried out well along each dataset but poorly between them as the spacing between the datasets is far larger than between points within a dataset.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: have you looked at interp2 as an alternative?

Comment: Could you provide example `x`, `y` and `z` that produce the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried Interp2. I have tried using Griddata, all of the interpolation methods reproduce the problem to varying degrees. The data for the plot above is at (http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=38900509992918495833) (x,y,z) are in columns (1,2,3) of the variable test.

Comment: The method is okay, your data is non-smooth. Just use `F = TriScatteredInterp (x,y,z, 'nearest');` which does no interpolation really and you see the problem.